# Update value for selectbox in streamlit in real-time

Tags: python, streamlit

How do I update the value of selectbox in streamlit dynamically?

here is a minimum non-working example

```
import streamlit as st
import time
def main():
 st.session_state['choice'] = list(range(2))
 st.selectbox("myoptions", options=st.session_state['choice'])
 while True:
  st.session_state['choice'] = list(range(5))
  time.sleep(2)
```

The reason I try to do this is to simulate the process of fetching new data and then updating the options.

In reality, i'll update the options every hour or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import streamlit as st
import time
import random
def skeleton():
    left, right = st.columns(2)
    with right:
        numbers = st.empty()
    return left, right, numbers

left, right, numbers = skeleton()
while True:
    with right:
        with numbers.container():
            st.selectbox('food',random.sample(range(10, 40), 4))
            time.sleep(2)
```